# How to share typescript types between nestjs backend and react frontend?

Tags: reactjs, rest, nestjs

Let's say I have a /createPost POST endpoint in my nestjs backend. The request and response object should be fully typed in the backend via the DTO. However, how do I bring these types into the frontend? I would like to have a typed post request object, so I can not enter invalid fields or missing fields in the post body. I would also like to have a typescript interface for the response. I want to REUSE the code from the backend. What's the best way to go about this? Is there some sort of type generator library?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a monorepo using nx workspace https://nx.dev/.
With that you can share models between all apps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use graphql, it can shares types with front

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is to create a **Github package** that you install (*can be private and is free* as opposed to doing this on NPM).

**Things to remember after you have published the package on your Github organization:**

1. Add a .npmrc file in the root folder of your project and write the following:

   `@your-organization-name:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com registry=https://registry.npmjs.org`
2. Remember that you will need to npm login for this to work like this:

   `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`

Username: your github username

Password is a `token` you create from Github -> Settings -> Developer settings.

I know I havent fully described the flow for you here on how to publish a package to Github, but the general idea should be clear.

Good luck!